# "Toggle" manytomanyfield in Django

Tags: django, database

I have two models which simplified look like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Person(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')
```

I want to easily be able to toggle these tags on and off for a person, what I've been doing so far is iterating some tags that are supposed to be toggled, like:

```
for tag in selected_tags:
    if person.tags.filter(pk=tag.id).exists():
        person.tags.remove(tag)
    else:
        person.tags.add(tag)
```

This does however cause lots of db queries and I'd like to be able to do it in just one query. Is there a "correct" way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

```
person.tags.set(selected_tags)
```

This is functionally equivalent to your code, but uses less queries, and, most importantly, is clean to read